# Python inheritance issue : AttributeError: 'AVL_Tree' object has no attribute 'score'

Tags: python, class, object, attributeerror

i am coding a program where i have an AVL tree stocking and sorting player based on there scores.
The player class is equivalent to a node with right and left sub nodes but with a name and a score:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, score=0):
        self.name=name
        self.score=score
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.height = 1
   
class AVL_Tree(object):
    def insert(self, root, player):
        if not root:
            return player
        if player.score < root.score: # the issue is here, you can ignore the rest
            root.left = self.insert(root.left, player)
        else:
            root.right = self.insert(root.right, player)
        root.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(root.left),
                              self.get_height(root.right))
        balance = self.get_balance(root)
        if balance > 1 and player.score < root.left.score:
            return self.right_rotate(root)
        if balance < -1 and player.score > root.right.score:
            return self.left_rotate(root)
        if balance > 1 and player.score > root.left.score:
            root.left = self.left_rotate(root.left)
            return self.right_rotate(root)
        if balance < -1 and player.score < root.right.score:
            root.right = self.right_rotate(root.right)
            return self.left_rotate(root)
        return root
```

but when i try to insert in the AVL it gives me this error:

in insert
if player.score < root.score:
AttributeError: 'AVL_Tree' object has no attribute 'score'

i set the **root attribute to ranking (the AVL tree)**, which is empty at start and fill with player instances afterward, and player attribute with the player to insert in.

I suppose that the program doesn't understand that the "root" in line 3 of insert() is actually an instance from the player class.
What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: We don't know what `root` is because you don't show the code that provides a value - so please make your code a [mre] - with the emphasis on _minimal_ i.e. just enough code+data to show the problem you are seeing - I should be able to paste your code from the question into a file and run it _without adding anything_ - so provide minimal data that shows the result you are seeing.

Comment: if you print `root` before the line where the exception happens, you'll see what type it is. Presumably it doesn't have a `.score` attribute - probably because code we can't see isn't providing something with a `.score` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that,
in may mains program i do

```
player1=Player("John",0)
ranking=AVLTree()
ranking.insert(ranking,player1)
```

so when ranking is empty, it should go into the first if condition in insert() and then, when ranking has a root, it should go over this step